# modify sql file on using command line on unix

Tags: regex, linux, command-line-interface

I have a .sql file that needs a little tweaking, speficially:

[xx_blah]

any pattern like the above needs to be changed to:

[Blah]

i.e. remove the xx_prefix and upper case the next character.

any tips?

Answer (score 3):

Simple `blah` replacement:

```
$ sed -e 's/\[[^]]*_blah]/[Blah]/g' old.sql > new.sql
```

More general:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\[[^]_]+_(.+?)]/[\u$1]/g' old.sql > new.sql
```

The reason to match the prefix with `[^]_]+` rather than `.+` is regular-expression quantifiers are greedy. For example, the latter when given `[xx_blah][xx_blah]` as input would gobble up as much as possible and match `xx_blah][xx`, not what you intended. Excluding right bracket and underscore is a safety stop.

The `\u` in the replacement is an [escape sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#ucfirst-EXPR) that uppercases the following letter.

If you prefer sed and your eyes don't get crossed from all the backslashes, go with

```
$ sed -e 's/\[[^]_]\+_\(.\+\?\)]/[\u\1]/g' old.sql > new.sql
```

Comment: none of these seemed to work?  could it be because the file was created on a windows machine? (spacing? tabs? newline?)

Comment: Was the output of `diff -ub old.sql new.sql` empty?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's/xx_\([a-z]\)/\u\1/' < old.sql > new.sql
```

Comment: Well, that depends on whether you ACTUALLY meant xx_

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the shell without external tools

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr
while read -r -a arr
do
    for((i=0;i<=${#arr};i++))                    
    do
        case "${arr[i]}" in
            *"[xx_"* );;&
            *"["*)
                arr[i]=${arr[i]//xx_/}
                arr[i]=${arr[i]^^${arr[i]:1:1}}
        esac
    done
    echo ${arr[@]}
done < "file"
```

example of output when run

```
PS1> more file
this is first line
this is second line
[xx_blah]
this is fourth line
blah [xx_blah] blah [xx_blah]
[someText]
end

PS1> ./mychanger.sh
this is first line
this is second line
[Blah]
this is fourth line
blah [Blah] blah [Blah]
[SomeText]
end
```